Issue with PPO agent taking action, sticking to a fixed value during training after 100K time-step
I'm facing an issue during training where my PPO agent consistently chooses actions close to the upper bound of the action range, sticking to a fixed value after 500K time-steps. The actions are within the range of (1e-12, 1e-3), and I'm using action scaling. What could be the main problem?
class SNLSOptEnv(gym.Env):
def init(self, task_name="Becker_Science2010", log_scale=False):
super(SNLSOptEnv, self).init()
    self.task_name = task_name
    self.log_tolerance = []

    # First action is the relative tolerance, second action is the absolute tolerance
    if log_scale:
        self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=-12, high=-3, shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32)
    else:
        self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=1e-12, high=1e-3, shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32)

    # Initialize variables for previous actions and performance metrics
    self.previous_action = np.zeros(2, dtype=np.float32)  # [NEW]
    self.previous_val = 0.0  # [NEW]
    self.previous_oval = 0.0  # [NEW]

    # Update the observation space to reflect the new state size
    # We'll define the state to include specific features
    num_features = 10  # Adjust this number based on the actual state size
    self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(num_features,), dtype=np.float32)

    self.cur_state = dict()
    self.previous_error = 0
    self.step_count = 0
    self.use_log_scale = log_scale

    self.eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
    self._init_matlab_engine()
    self.init_rtol = self.eng.eval("ar.config.rtol")
    self.init_atol = self.eng.eval("ar.config.atol")

    self.noise = NormalActionNoise(mean=np.zeros(2), sigma=0.03 * np.ones(2))

def _init_matlab_engine(self):
    self.eng.addpath("stepwise_snls/")
    self.eng.cd("arFramework3/Examples/" + self.task_name)

    out = StringIO()
    err = StringIO()
    self.eng.eval("arLoadLatest", stdout=out, stderr=err)
    recompile = False
    if "Warning: No results folder exist" in out.getvalue():
        print(f"No results folder found, creating a new one")
        self.eng.mkdir("Results", nargout=0)
        recompile = True

    if "Please compile" in out.getvalue() or recompile:
        print(f"Not found compiled model, now trying to compile the model, it may take a while")
        self.eng.Setup(nargout=0)
        self.eng.arSave('', nargout=0)

    # Save the initial ODE parameter
    self.init_ode_param = self.eng.eval("ar.p", nargout=1)

def parse_snls_optim_output(self, optim_data):
    # This function can be implemented to parse optim_data if needed
    return optim_data

def parse_snls_rl_output(self, rl_data):
    state = {}
    for key, value in rl_data.items():
        if key == 'success':
            state['success'] = 1
        elif key == 'EXITFLAG':
            state['EXITFLAG'] = value if not np.isnan(value) else 0
        else:
            state[key] = value
    return state

def step(self, action):
    self.step_count += 1

    # Add noise to the action for exploration
    noisy_action = action + self.noise()
    print(f"Step {self.step_count}: Noisy Action before clipping: {noisy_action}")

    # Clip the action based on the scale
    if self.use_log_scale:
        noisy_action = np.clip(noisy_action, -12, -3)
    else:
        noisy_action = np.clip(noisy_action, 1e-12, 1e-3)

    print(f"Step {self.step_count}: Clipped Noisy Action: {noisy_action}")

    # Apply the action to the MATLAB environment
    self.apply_action_to_matlab(noisy_action)

    # Execute one step in the SNLS optimization via MATLAB
    optim_out, rl_out = self.eng.arSnlsStep(nargout=2)
    rl_state = self.parse_snls_rl_output(rl_out)
    optim_state = self.parse_snls_optim_output(optim_out)
    self.cur_state = {**rl_state, **optim_state}

    # Extract necessary values from rl_state
    val = rl_state.get('val', 0.0)
    oval = rl_state.get('oval', 0.0)

    # Compute performance deltas
    delta_val = val - self.previous_val  # [NEW]
    delta_oval = oval - self.previous_oval  # [NEW]

    # Update previous metrics
    self.previous_val = val  # [NEW]
    self.previous_oval = oval  # [NEW]

    # Construct the next observation explicitly
    next_obs = np.array([
        val,
        oval,
        rl_state.get('diff', 0.0),
        rl_state.get('runtimeODE', 0.0),
        self.previous_action[0],
        self.previous_action[1],
        delta_val,
        delta_oval,
        rl_state.get('iter', 0.0),
        rl_state.get('ratio', 0.0)
        # Add more features if needed and adjust num_features accordingly
    ], dtype=np.float32)

    # Update previous action
    self.previous_action = noisy_action  # [NEW]

    # Calculate the reward
    reward = self.calculate_reward(rl_state, optim_state, noisy_action)

    # Check if the episode is terminated
    terminated, truncated = self.is_done(rl_state, optim_state)

    return next_obs, reward, terminated, truncated, {"EXITFLAG": rl_state.get("EXITFLAG", 0)}

def is_done(self, rl_state, optim_state):
    # Determine if the episode should terminate
    terminated = rl_state.get("EXITFLAG", 0) > 0
    truncated = False  # You can set conditions for truncation if needed
    return terminated, truncated

def calculate_reward(self, rl_state, optim_state, action):
    val = rl_state.get('val', 0.0)
    oval = rl_state.get('oval', 0.0)
    runtime = max(rl_state.get('runtimeODE', 1.0), 1e-8)

# Improvement calculation, avoiding division by small oval
    improvement = (oval - val) / oval if oval > 1e-8 else 0.0

# Penalty for actions near the boundaries
    action_range = self.action_space.high - self.action_space.low
    normalized_action = (action - self.action_space.low) / action_range
    action_penalty = np.sum(np.abs(normalized_action - 0.5)) * 0.05  # Reduced penalty

# State-dependent reward (success bonus)
    success_bonus = 1.0 if rl_state.get('success', 0) == 1 else 0.0

# Final reward calculation
    reward = improvement - (runtime / 10) - action_penalty + success_bonus
    return np.clip(reward, -10.0, 10.0)


def apply_action_to_matlab(self, action):
    if self.use_log_scale:
        # Convert action from log scale to real scale
        action = 10 ** action  # Assuming log base 10
    # Ensure the action is in the correct format for MATLAB
    action = np.clip(action, 1e-12, 1e-3)

    print(f"Step {self.step_count}: Passing action to MATLAB - rtol = {action[0]}, atol = {action[1]}")

    # Pass the action to MATLAB
    self.eng.eval(f"ar.config.rtol = {action[0]};", nargout=0)
    self.eng.eval(f"ar.config.atol = {action[1]};", nargout=0)

def reset(self, seed=None):
    print("Resetting the environment")
    self.eng.clear("arSnlsStep", nargout=0)

    # Reset ODE Parameter
    if seed is not None:
        self.eng.eval("ar.p = arRandomPars(1, %d);" % seed, nargout=0)
    else:
        seed = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2 ** 32 - 1)
        self.eng.eval("ar.p = arRandomPars(1, %d);" % seed, nargout=0)

    # Reset variables
    self.cur_state = np.zeros(self.observation_space.shape, dtype=np.float32)  # [MODIFIED]
    self.previous_error = None
    self.step_count = 0

    # Initialize previous actions and metrics
    self.previous_action = np.zeros(2, dtype=np.float32)  # [NEW]
    self.previous_val = 0.0  # [NEW]
    self.previous_oval = 0.0  # [NEW]

    return self.cur_state, {}

def render(self, mode='human'):
    raise NotImplementedError

def close(self):
    self.eng.quit()

